# How to loop through a code only once then loop through other code over and over?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
def urlCopy():
    py.moveTo(x=420,y=11,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #share
    py.moveTo(x=1054,y=946,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #copy
    py.moveTo(x=1175,y=630,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #1st tab
    py.moveTo(x=252,y=16,duration=2)
    py.click()
    py.moveTo(x=1093, y=517)
    py.click() 
    if scrol == True:
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        varrs = py.hotkey('ctrl','v')
        global scrol
        scrol = False
        
    else:
        py.scroll(-300)
        py.tripleClick()
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        varrs = py.hotkey('ctrl','v')
```

> I am trying to copy youtube videos title and save it in other website.I want the code to run without scrolling at first loop and then always scrolling with next loops.I am going to loop this function again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
scrol = True
def urlCopy():
    global scrol #define scrol as global before you reference it
    py.moveTo(x=420,y=11,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #share
    py.moveTo(x=1054,y=946,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #copy
    py.moveTo(x=1175,y=630,duration=2)
    py.click()
    #1st tab
    py.moveTo(x=252,y=16,duration=2)
    py.click()
    py.moveTo(x=1093, y=517)
    py.click() 
    if scrol == True: #referenced here
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        varrs = py.hotkey('ctrl','v')
        scrol = False
        
    else:
        py.scroll(-300)
        py.tripleClick()
        py.moveTo(x=154, y=420,duration=2)
        py.tripleClick()
        varrs = py.hotkey('ctrl','v')
```

Comment: I also want when my one condition is running second should not execute.

Comment: This method will do that.

Comment: @treklucifer i tried to apply it to your code to my best understanding.

Comment: @treklucifer see updated answer.

Comment: I am actually going to loop the function again and again.

Comment: @treklucifer in that case see the updated answer.

Comment: @treklucifer what issues are you having with your current code? or if you try my version what issues with it?

Comment: see actually its a loop of functions infinitly.when we enter our function and enter your code it all repeats itself.

Comment: The entire script or just the function? @treklucifer

Comment: my code just 3 functions endlessly looping into each other. But a code from a function should be performed just once even if functions are looping again and again. A part of code that is in one of the function should be executed just till i kill the program

Comment: @treklucifer the please be specific as to why my solution doesn't work, because it defines `scrol = True` outside of the function (which means it doesn't reset when the function loops, therefore the intended result should be created. if this is not the case please explain further.